# Rally App SDK 2.0: rallymultiobjectpicker fails to load option text

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

I am having an issue with the rallymultiobjectpicker, where there is a lack of option text loaded, so there is this banding effect with the list items and their checkboxes. There are no errors in the console, so I have no idea what is wrong. I have tried to minimize the amount of config options specified to the basic modelType, but the issue still persists. I am using it to display tags, if that should make any difference. It seems to work in a standalone app, but I don't see why any of the other components in the larger app would cause loading conflicts, and not throw any errors.

Here is an image depicting the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynG5p.png

Note: I guess I should note that this was in preview 1. They seem to load fine in preview 2. I am not sure if there is a recommended fix for preview 1. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing this out and for clarifying the behavior is restricted to 2.0p1. I don't believe that a fix will be forthcoming for preview 1 - the developers are currently working hard on 2.0p3, which will have a number of enhancements and bug fixes. I'd recommend keeping an eye on http://developer.rallydev.com for the latest and greatest version during the preview period and updating your code to match.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I understand that they probably won't be fixing any issues with the first preview, but just thought there might be some kind of workaround, or specific config setting that could be specified to remedy this. In any case, I have now settled on preview 2, so I guess it may be a moot point.

Comment: Thanks, I can definitely understand the interest in a workaround etc. I'm not familiar enough with the Ext "guts" of AppSDK2 preview to provide a super-informed answer, other than to say that in preview, some upgrades to the underlying Ext as well as the AppSDK2 Api layer could break some things in non-backwards compatible ways. That said, I don't have data that this is the case for this particular situation. Maybe one of the Rally developer team could weigh in to clarify.